# Neo4j-Cypher: Remove a node from a path and maintain the link to all nodes of the path

Tags: neo4j, path, cypher, graph-databases

I want to remove one node from a path, without jeopardizing the original path nodes.

This is my test db:

[image: Test DB]

I want to remove node (2) from the path, but I want nodes 1, 3, 4, and 5 to stay linked in the path.

Is there a way to do it in one query? So far I have the following:

```
MATCH p = (:Connect)-[:to*]-(:Connect)
WITH nodes(p) AS connectNodes
UNWIND connectNodes AS connectNode
WITH distinct connectNode
WHERE connectNode.connectID = 2
DETACH DELETE (connectNode)
```

This will remove node 2 and unlinkes the path

[image: Unlinked graph]

How can maintain the link between the nodes of the original path without node 2?

**EDIT**:

I solved it by modifying the accepted answer's response

```
//Make sure node (n) belongs to the path
MATCH (n:Connect {cID:2})-[:to*]-(:Connect {cID:5})
//get attached nodes, if any, ignoring directions
OPTIONAL MATCH (oa:connect)-[:to]-(n)-[:to]-(ob:connect)
//make sure nothing is duplicated 
WHERE oa.cID <> ob.cID
//Use FOREACH to mimic if/else. Only merge oa to ob if they exist. Query fails without it
FOREACH (_ IN case when oa IS NOT NULL then [true] else [] end |
    MERGE (oa)-[:to {created: 1542103211}]-(ob)
)
//Get n, and get all connected nodes to it, and delete the relationship(s)
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:to]-(:Connect) DELETE r
```

Comment: What should your preferred solution look like? Scenario I: 5->4->1 and 3->1, Scenario II: 5->4<-1 and 3->1  Scenario III: 5->4<-3 and 3->1 or Scenario IV: 5->4->3 and 3->1?

Comment: @ThirstForKnowledge direction doesn't matter, as long as I can get all nodes of the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the simplest way to do it would be to match the paths that would be broken, and then create the new links in the same cypher that deletes the node.

```
// Match the target node for deletion
MATCH (n{id:2})
// Match broken paths, if any
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[ra]->(n)-[rb]->(b)
// Create new link to replace destroyed ones
CREATE (a)-[r:to]->(b)
// Copy properties over, if any
SET r+=ra, r+=rb
// Remove target node
DETACH DELETE n
// If you want to keep the node and just disconnect it, replace last line with
// OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:to]-() DELETE r
```

There are [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) functions you can use to create a relation with a dynamic type if you want to copy the type from one of the removed relationships.

Comment: after modifying this query, it worked (please see the edited OP). But it fails on edge nodes. It only works on nodes that are connected to more than 1 node. In my original graph, it fails on 1, 3, and 5. How can I make it dynamic enough to work on any node?

Comment: @TarekDeeb detach delete was suppose to clean up the edges, if you want to keep the node, and just remove it from all graphs, you can replace detach delete with `OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r:to]-() DELETE r`

Comment: This will just remove the relationship. I need to maintain the link to the original path. So if I have (1)-(2)-(3) and remove (2), your solution works, and I'll get (1)-(3). But If I want to remove (3), I want to still be left with (1)-(2). The removed node will not be deleted, but only not belonging to the original path.

Comment: @TarekDeeb With the replace I gave you, (1)-(2)-(3) target 3 will result in (1)-(2) and (3), I don't understand what else you want to happen (your description sounds like that is what you wanted)

Comment: I'm sorry I just saw your edit in your response. I modified the query to work on both cases and all is well. Check the modified query in my OP. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @TarekDeeb It's good, just replace WITH with WITH DISTINCT to cut down the row count, or remove the WITH so that the cypher planner has permission to do that match-delete in parallel. (I don't think you are getting any benefit from the with as is)

Comment: I tried it without the `WITH`, but it was giving me an error that I have to use `WITH` between `MERGE` and `OPTIONAL MATCH`. That's the only reason I added it

Answer (score 1):

An additional opportunity would be the removal of node "2" and the usage of the APOC procedure "Redirect relationship to". You can find a detailed description and illustrating images in the [procedure documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_redirect_relationship_to).